# The quotient of a manifold by a submanifold is never a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold. Let $S$ be a connected embedded submanifold of **positive dimension and co-dimension**,  which is also a closed subset of $M$.

**Is it true that the quotient space $M /S$ (i.e the space obtained by identifying all $S$ to a single point) is never a manifold?**

Here is an attempt to show this:

If we denote the equivalence relation by $E \subseteq M \times M$, then it is proven in Bourbaki (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/496628/104576)), that the quotient $M /S$ inherits from $M$ a smooths structure if and only if:

- $E$ is a closed submanifold of $M \times M$, and
- The first projection $\pi_1: E \to M$ is a submersion

In our case $E=\{(x,x)|x \notin S \}\cup S \times S=\{(x,x)|x \in M \}\cup S \times S$

---

**Now assume $E$ is a submanifold of $M \times M$.**

Then, since $(S\times S)^c$ is open in $M \times M$, $E \cap (S\times S)^c=\{(x,x)|x \in S^c \}$ is open in $E$.

Since $S$ is closed in $M$, $S^c$ is open in $M$, so $\dim E =\dim \big( E \cap (S\times S)^c \big)=\dim \big( \operatorname{diag}(S^c) \big)=\dim(S^c)=\dim M:=n$

If I am not mistaken, then for every point $s \in S$, $\dim_{(s,s)}E=(n-s)+2s > n$ which is a contradiction.

The part of $(n-s)$ comes from paths spanning the complementary directions to $T_sS$ in the diagonal, i.e $\alpha(t)=(\beta(t),\beta(t))$ starting from $(s,s)$, such that $\dot \beta(0)=v \in T_sM\setminus T_sS$. The part of $2s$ comes from the freedom of movement inside the manifold $S \times S$.

Is this true? Is there a shorter (direct) argument? (perhaps one which does not use Bourbaki's result)

Comment: I have added the assumption $M$ is connected. Otherwise one could  take $M=M_1 \cup M_2$ to be a disjoint union of two connected components, and choose $S=M_2$. Then $M/S = M_1 \cup \{ \cdot \}$ is a manifold. Another possible way to eliminate these kind of trivial counter-exmaples, is by requiring the dimension of $M/S$ to be constant, and that of $M$ to be positive.

Comment: Great question, I had a lot of fun with it.

Comment: Doesn't taking $M = \Bbb R P^2$ and $S = \textrm{(some projective line)}$ make $M / S$ a $2$-sphere?

Comment: Reading @MikeMiller's quite good answer, I see that this is basically a real version of his first example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't carefully read the proof in your post; I am more interested in whether this subset is a *topological manifold*, rather than a smooth one such that the quotient map is a submersion, which as you say is not true, and straightforward to see; the differential must necessarily kill the tangent space of $S$, but the quotient "manifold" is still of the same dimension as $M$, because $S$ has positive codimension.

And yes, this is indeed possible. Take $\Bbb{CP}^1 \subset \Bbb{CP}^2$. Collapsing this to a point gives you a copy of $S^4$. (To see this straightforwardly, note that $\Bbb{CP}^2$ is obtained by gluing a $D^4$ to $S^2$ by the Hopf map on the boundary; collapsing the $S^2$ gives us a space obtained by collapsing the boundary of $D^4$ to a point: $S^4$.)

Here is how I came up with the example, and the general principle at play here. The tubular neighborhood theorem says there is a neighborhood of a submanifold $S$ diffeomorphic to a vector bundle (the normal bundle) over $S$. So it suffices to answer it for this case. Now if $E$ is a bundle, and $S$ the zero section, $E/S$ is contractible, so has trivial homology. This implies that $H_{*-1}(E/S - [S]) \cong H_*(E/S,E/S-[S])$ by the relative long exact sequence. The first group is isomorphic to $H_*(E-S)$ (they're homeomorphic!), which deformation retracts onto the unit sphere bundle of the vector bundle. Now we can conclude: If $E/S$ was a manifold, then the local homology at $[S]$ $H_*(E/S,E/S-[S])$ would have the same homology of the appropriate-dimensional sphere. This is false for many, many vector bundles (for instance, if you collapse a circle in a manifold, the result is never a manifold) but not *always* false; the way the above example came to mind is that the circle bundle over $S^2$ with Euler class 1 is $S^3$, and hence of course *does* have the same homology as $S^3$...

Now here's a full proof that the quotient is a manifold if and only if the sphere bundle is a sphere. (It's quite clean, cleaner than the above, but I thought I would leave it in to show my thought process.) The quotient $E/S$ is homeomorphic to the cone on the sphere bundle. The above argument shows that whenever the sphere bundle has the wrong homology, the quotient is not a manifold. When it has the right homology, but is not simply connected, follow the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1577714/98602). Now any closed simply connected manifold with the same homology as a sphere is a sphere, by the Poincare conjecture.

OK, when is a sphere bundle a sphere? Suppose $S^n$ fits into a fibration with fiber $S^k, k>0$, and base $M$. Then $M$ is necessarily simply connected, and a straightforward spectral sequence argument shows that necessarily either the cohomology of the base is $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^n)$ where $|x|$ is even. This is only possible if $|x|$ is 2 or 4 (or $|x|=8$ and $n \leq 3$); see proposition 4L.10 of Hatcher. So necessarily the base has the same cohomology ring as $\Bbb{CP}^n$ or $\Bbb{HP}^n$ and is simply connected (or the base is $S^8 = \Bbb{OP}^1$ or has the cohomology ring of $\Bbb{OP}^2$) In the case $k=0$ the same holds with $\Bbb{RP}^n$ and $\Bbb Z/2$-coefficients. Unfortunately, this is as far as we go: it is entirely possible that this is *not* the obvious fibration. For instance, there are fake projective spaces, both [real](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_real_projective_spaces) and [complex](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_complex_projective_spaces), all of which (by the argument given on the latter page) support sphere bundles with total space $S^n$. I'm sure there's also a classification of fake quaternionic projective spaces. This is probably a complete classification of sphere bundles with appropriate total space: all are $S^0$, $S^1$, or $S^3$ bundles over a fake projective space (or again the case of $\Bbb{OP}^2$). I am not going to carry out the details that this is the case. (EDIT: Yes, this is the classification; simply connected manifolds with this cohomology ring are homotopy equivalent to the appropriate projective space, because they have a CW decomposition with a cell in each degree $kn$, $k=2,4,8$; then these are homotopy equivalent to the projective spaces by an inductive argument.)

Comment: (+1) Blowing up points (or rather, blowing down after blowing up) furnishes more examples. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang And all of the examples "look like this", by the argument I've just edited in.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true as stated trivially if we let $S=M$, since $M/M$ is a single point and a zero dimensional manifold.

But for a non-trivial example, consider the circle, $M=S^1$, and let $S$ be any connected proper submanifold, a.k.a. an arc of the circle.  Then $M/S$ is still going to be a circle.

**Edit below**

Additional example with $M$ having boundary and $S$ is a closed submanifold: Let $M$ be the closed ball of dimension $n$, $B^n$.  Then let the boundary be $S=S^{n-1}$.  Then $M/S=S^n$.

I would not be surprised if this is true for $M$ and $S$ closed as Mike suggests though.

Comment: They presumably want closed manifolds.

Comment: An arc is not closed (if it is then it is a submanifold with boundary). Also, let's assume $S$ has a positive co-dimension, so the question won't become trivial.

Comment: +1 Your first example violates the positive codimension requirement, but I note that it was not added until after your post, so you cannot be blamed for lacking prescience. The final example is excellent.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you!